# Why do I get DBIx "No such relationship" error on one of the two clone instances of perl Catalyst?

Tags: mysql, perl, web-applications, relationship, catalyst

I replicated a Perl catalyst web application on a new server, making sure catalyst, MySQL, and all required Perl modules have the same versions across both servers. But I keep getting a strange DBIx error message when I try to login on one server.

This is the error.

> [error] DBIx::Class::ResultSet::search(): No such relationship
>   committee_members on Committee at
>   /mnt/data/www/apps/org/script/../lib/org/Controller/Users.pm line 57
>   [debug] Response Code: 500; Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8;
>   Content-Length: 204782

The relationship clearly exists in the database. Has any one else had this issue?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It exists in the database, does it exist in your DBIx::Class code?

Comment: It's not talking about something in the database, it's talking about a relationship defined in your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was the problem - the module DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader was not up to date.

The original version catalyst and related modules worked fine with the code as it was (with relationship/table nomenclature of olden times) but some modules, not all, were updated along the way breaking the back-compatibility of above module. When that was updated too, the warnings were reported and relationship names were automatically resolved (I still need to see the details..).

It was able to resolve some back-compatibility issues that were left out of the intermediate release. 
see 
[http://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader::Manual::UpgradingFromV4](http://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx%3a%3aClass%3a%3aSchema%3a%3aLoader%3a%3aManual%3a%3aUpgradingFromV4)